# What exactly does this code do to check for collision

Tags: c++

What exactly does this code do to check for collision

```
void Map::entities_collide(Pacman* pacman) {
    list <Entity*> temp = entities;

    for (Entity* entity : temp) {
        if ((pacman->get_position()->GetX() == entity->get_position()->GetX()) && abs(pacman->get_position()->GetY() - entity->get_position()->GetY()) <= 2 ||
            (pacman->get_position()->GetY() == entity->get_position()->GetY()) && abs(pacman->get_position()->GetX() - entity->get_position()->GetX()) <= 2) {
            pacman->eat(*entity);
            entities.remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the entity is located in + with line sizes 4 and the pacman is in the center of +, then the pacman eats the entity.

Comment: @S.M. Actually, the code has a few logical errors in it.  Basically the positioning of the && makes it only check for identical X positions (and identical Y positions) and the positioning of the || makes pacman "eat" the entity only if it is on the same row OR column of the entity.  Unless I read it wrong....  (and there seems to be parenthesis misplacement too)

Comment: @S.M. Really?  The first comparison says pacman.X equals entity.X.  The second says pacman.X is within 2 units of entity.X.  The and between them means that it will only trigger when both are correct, so the second statement is redundant.  Then the || between the "X and Y" checks means that (if they fixed the parenthesis) only one of the X or Y would have to match, not both.  I think there's a logical error in this if statement.

Comment: @S.M. X or Y doesn't matter, in either dimension, the distance is 2 units from the pacman; but, the problem is it's AND-ed with a "exactly matches the pacman" in that same dimension.  So, even if it's two units nearby, since it's not an exact match, then AND will compare to a false value (not an exact match) so all of the coding for the "two units distance" will burn CPU cycles but never do more than the exact match.  Odds are the exact match code should be removed.

Comment: `it's AND-ed with a "exactly matches the pacman" in that same dimension.` No, it is not. It checks for equality in ONE dimension and for nearby in the OTHER dimension.

Comment: @S.M.  Sorry, you're absolutely right.  In my scrolling, I got my X's and Y's mixed up.  It's a simple "anything 2 units from pacman" matcher.  I'm going to delete my answer as it's wrong.  Thanks for sticking to your position, and making me reread the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
• • • • • • •
• • • E • • •
• • • E • • •
• E E P E E •
• • • E • • •
• • • E • • •
• • • • • • •
```

The pacman is P. The expression tests if the entity is located in P or E. If yes, the pacman eats the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pacman` eats the entity when one of the two conditions occur (hence the || between the two similar clauses):

- If the X's between the `pacman` and the `entity` match, then it
  checks to see if the difference between the Y's is within `pacman's`
  biting range, which is apparently 2 squares.
- If the Y's between the `pacman` and the `entity` match, then it
  checks to see if the difference between the X's is within `pacman's`
  biting range, which is apparently 2 squares.

This preserves the `pacman` ability to only eat above, below, left, or right of the `pacman` but oddly it allows the `pacman` to eat zero, one, or two squares from its position.

```
abs(pacman->get_position()->GetY() - entity->get_position()->GetY()) <= 2
```

finds the difference along the Y axis.  If the absolute value of the difference is two or less, then `pacman` bites.  Assuming the absolute value is two or less, then the actual possible values would have been -2, -1, 0, 1, or 2.